# Position of particle indicated by matter waves

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

In quantum mechanics, with the understanding of de Broglie principle, we realise that matter behaves like waves, but I have a doubt that any wave function doesn't have a fixed indication of position of matter, whereas for larger particles present around us, we do have fixed position although quantum mechanics claim to have a wave discription for that as well.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

What we need is two things. Uncertainty principle and superposition of states. 
If the state has a fixed momentum, then it’s position is completely undefined. This can be visualised as follows:[image]

Here the wavelength is defined, thus momentum is defined. But the position is completely undefined. This has to be the case as dictated by the uncertainty principle.

However now if your position is well-defined, then uncertainty principle demands that the momentum must be ill-defined. That means the state must be a sum of waves of various wavelengths. This can be seen below where I have added waves of 5 different wavelengths:[image]

As can be seen that by just adding a few waves, we are getting a function that seems to be localised around a point. This means that as we increase the number of different wavelengths we add the state gets more and more localised. But in doing so, we no longer have a definitive momentum.

This is all of course just a non-rigorous explanation but if you want more details I urge you to look at how momentum and position are Fourier conjugated of each other and how this can be seen from that perspective.